# MySQLi throws PHP error on failed connection

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli

I wrote some code to connect to my database, it worked perfectly when running on my Windows computer:

```
<?php
    include_once(__DIR__ . '/config.php');

    $sqlc = new mysqli('p:' . DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if ($sqlc->connect_error)
    {
        die('Unable to connect to server or database.');
    }
?>
```

If the connection is successful, everything works as expected and when the connection fails, it outputs the correct error message (`Unable to connect to server or database.`).

However, when I upload this file to my Raspberry Pi (Arch Linux, latest Apache, PHP and MariaDB) the PHP script fails when the connection isn't successful. I tried enabling display_errors in the config and it outputs this error:

`Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'raspi' in /srv/http/tools/sqlconnect.php on line 4`

How do I get my PHP script to output my error message (`Unable to connect to server or database.`) again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$sqlc = new mysqli('p:' . DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die('Unable to connect to server or database.');
```

Comment: Works perfectly and also fixes a few other problems I just discovered. Thank you, I will accept your answer as soon as I can!